# Where is the nviz tool in qgis 2.14 with GRASS 7.0.3?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, 3d, nviz

I hope Im not blind but I looked in the grass tools (modules) and qgis plugins but couldnt find it. When i try to run nviz from GRASS the whole programme chrashes just before concluding. Its a relativly small DEM with only 5m resolution from a river valley.

Are there any other opensource programs to model a 3d image (with orthophoto on top)?

Answer (score 2):

I have done all modules of grass7.0.3 works but nviz7 NO!
Could be a PATH problems. The nviz7 command isn't under grass7.0.3 dir!?
I found nvzi7.py in the ./qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/nviz7.py dir but how could by call!?

Answer (score 1):

NVIZ is located under Grass 7 as you can see below:

[image]

Maybe  you need to activate the tool from `Processing menu > options` as shown below:

[image]

If also didn't work, then you may need to reinstall QGIS 2.14 from `OSGeo4W > Advance install` and follow the steps until you find the following window, and make sure to install Grass 7.0.3

[image]